# one-to-many relation: not able to persist values into many side entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

### **Customer Entity**

```
            @Entity

            @NamedQuery(name = "findAllCustomer", query = "SELECT i FROM Customer i")

            public class Customer implements Serializable {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Id
                private int id;
                private String firstName;
                private String lastName;
                private String address;
                @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
                private Collection<Rent> rent;

                public Customer(){

                }

                public Customer(int id,String firstName, String lastName, String address){
                    this.id = id;
                    this.firstName = firstName;
                    this.lastName = lastName;
                    this.address = address;
                }

                public int getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                public String getFirstName(){
                    return firstName;
                }
                public void setFirstName(String firstName){
                    this.firstName = firstName;
                }
                public String getLastName(){
                    return lastName;
                }
                public void setLastName(String lastName){
                    this.lastName = lastName;
                }
                public String getAddress(){
                    return address;
                }
                public void setAddress(String address){
                    this.address = address;
                }


                public Collection<Rent> getRent() {
                    return rent;
                }

                public void setRent(Collection<Rent> rent) {
                    this.rent = rent;
                }

                 public void addRent(Rent rent) {
                    this.getRent().add(rent);
                }

            }

       *
```

### Rent Entity

```
            @Entity

            @NamedQuery(name = "findAllRent", query = "SELECT i FROM Rent i")

            public class Rent implements Serializable {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                private Long id;
                private String item;
                private int days;
                private int rDate;
                @JoinColumn(name="VENDORID")
                @ManyToOne
                private Customer customer;

                public Rent(){

                }
                public Rent(String item, int days, int rDate){
                    this.item = item;
                    this.days = days;
                    this.rDate= rDate;
                }

                public Long getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(Long id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }
                public String getItem() {
                    return item;
                }

                public void setItem(String item) {
                    this.item = item;
                }
                public int getDays() {
                    return days;
                }

                public void setDays(int days ) {
                    this.days = days;
                }
                public int getRDate() {
                    return rDate;
                }

                public void setRDate(int rDate ) {
                    this.rDate = rDate;
                }

                public Customer getCustomer() {
                    return customer;
                }

                public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
                    this.customer = customer;
                }

            }
```

## EJB

```
            public void createRent (int currentCustomer,String item, int days, int rDate ){

                        Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, currentCustomer);
                        Rent rent = new Rent(item, days, rDate);        
                        customer.addRent(rent);
                        rent.setCustomer(customer);
                        em.merge(customer);

                }
```

## controller

```
            //currentCustomer has the id of the  customer for whom the rent is being created//

             public int getCurrentCustomer() {

                    return currentCustomer;

                }

                public void setCurrentCustomer(int currentCustomer) {

                    this.currentCustomer = currentCustomer;

                }

            public String doCreateRent() {

                   System.out.println(""+currentCustomer);

                    try {            

                        customerEJB.createRent(this.currentCustomer, this.item, this.days, this.rDate);  

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.printf( "Problem adding line items to order ID {0}");
                    }
                    return "listRent.xhtml";
                }
```

## listCustomer.xhtml; lists the customers and when clicked on id it takes to the newRent.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <title>List all the customer</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>List all the customer</h1>
    <hr/>

    <h:dataTable value="#{customerController.customerList}" var="it" border="1">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id"/>
            </f:facet>
```

i thjink this is where iam messing the application

```
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink id="customer_Id_link" action="newRent.xhtml">
                    <h:outputText value="#{it.id}"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{customerController.currentCustomer}" value="#{it.id}" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>            
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="FirstName"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{it.firstName}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="LastName"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{it.lastName}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Address"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{it.address}"/>
        </h:column>    

    </h:dataTable>
    <h:form>


        <h:link outcome="index.xhtml" value="mainpage"/>
    </h:form>
    <hr/>
    <i>APress - Beginning Java EE 6</i>
</h:body>
</html>
```

## newRent.xhtml

```
    <h:head>
        <title>Creates a new rent</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Create a new rent</h1>
        <hr/>
        <h:form>
            <table border="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Item : "/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText value="#{customerController.item}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputLabel value="days : "/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText value="#{customerController.days}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Date : "/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText value="#{customerController.RDate}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <h:commandButton value="Create a rent" action="#{customerController.doCreateRent()}"/>

        </h:form>
        <hr/>
        <i>APress - Beginning Java EE 6</i>

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

## Output

```
    INFO: currentcustomer0
    WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CustomerEJB, method: public void shoeb.CustomerEJB.createRent(int,java.lang.String,int,int)
    WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.createRent(Unknown Source)
        at shoeb.__EJB31_Generated__CustomerEJB__Intf____Bean__.createRent(Unknown Source)
        at shoeb.CustomerController.doCreateRent(CustomerController.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at shoeb.CustomerEJB.createRent(CustomerEJB.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        ... 47 more

    INFO: Problem adding line items to order ID {0}
```

Comment: guys please help me out, I am unable to persist rent values into the database. had been trying for two days straight. i think there is some problem in my EJB code.

Comment: this the error that keeps comingWARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CustomerEJB, method: public void shoeb.CustomerEJB.createRent(int,java.lang.String,int,int)                               
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException

Comment: The key is to read and post the exception stack trace. It should tell you what and where the problem is. Remove your catch(Exception) block. It hides the actual exception that is thrown, preventing you from knowing what the problem is.

Comment: change position of this 2 lines in your ejb and after that merge customer : `customer.addRent(rent);
        rent.setCustomer(customer);`

Comment: thanks JB Nizet, Rasoul Taheri, pmp. i did made the changes you guys recommended. but the application still does not work, the actual problem is in passing the currentCustomer from listCustomer.xhtml, cause when i try to print the currentCustomer in controller it print 0 as you can see in the output section.

Comment: what iam trying to do is when i click on the customer id it should store the currentCustomer in controller and take me to the newRent.xhtml and save rent for that customer. thank you guys. help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void createRent (int currentCustomer,String item, int days, int rDate ){

    try{

        Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, currentCustomer);
        Rent rent = new Rent(item, days, rDate);
        customer.addRent(rent);
        rent.setCustomer(customer);
        em.merge(customer);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EJBException(e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Because relationship is bidirectional, you need to specify entities for each other. 
Here is:

```
If the OneToMany uses a foreign key in the target object's table JPA 
requires that the relationship be bi-directional 
(inverse ManyToOne relationship must be defined in the target object), 
and the source object must use the mappedBy attribute to define the mapping
```

and the link:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Comment: in controller where do set the customer id and item? You are passing those parameters to `createRent`. Put a logger in that method to make sure you are passing the correct parameters. Most likely you are passing 0 as `currentCustomer` or 0 as item

Comment: customerId iam setting as currentCustomer. when I setCurrentCustomer and print the value, it is displaying the right id. but in method createRent it is trying to pass currentCustomer as 0